# Conditions for unicity of system solutions of a non locally lipschitz IVPs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying unicity of the solutions of IVP in ordinary differential systems.

In this context, we have the following result for differential equations:

> If $f(x,t):R\times R\to R$ is continuous and decreasing in $x$ for every $t$ then the IVPs associated to the equation $x'=f(x,t)$ have unique solutions.

Is there an analog of this result for higher dimensional systems?

Something like:

> If $f(X,t):R^n\times R\to R^n$ is continuous and decreasing in norm with respect to each $X_i$ for every $t$ then the IVPs associated to the system $X'=f(X,t)$ have unique solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an analog:
$$
\langle X-Y,F(X,t)-F(Y,t)\rangle\le0\quad\forall X,Y\in\Bbb R^n,\quad\forall t\ge t_0.
$$
Here $\langle,\rangle$ is the dot product in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Sweet! Can you point me to a proof or an intuition of why it is true?

Comment: Same proof as the one dimensional case. If $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ are two solutions with the same initial value at $t_0$, differentiate $\|X(t)-Y(t)\|^2$ with respect to $t$.